# Funciones en Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo un problema, tengo una función que al llamarla me muestra los datos de dos tablas

Esta es la función

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION visualizar()
RETURNS TABLE (codigo int,cliente varchar,proveedor varchar,fecha timestamp,total int,producto varchar,cantidad int,precio int,subtotal int)
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY 
SELECT f.codigo,f.cliente,f.proveedor,f.fecha,f.total,d.producto,d.cantidad,d.precio,d.subtotal FROM factura f,detalle d WHERE f.codigo=d.codigo;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Pero lo que yo quisiera es que al llamarla función me traiga ciertos datos y al seleccionar uno de esos datos me cargue todos los datos que tenga en las dos tablas

hasta ahora lo e intentado así

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cargar()
RETURNS TABLE(codigo int,cliente varchar,proveedor varchar,fecha timestamp)
AS $$
BEGIN
return query
select f.codigo,f.cliente,f.proveedor,f.fecha FROM factura f;
IF codigo::integer = 1 THEN
 SELECT f.codigo,f.cliente,f.proveedor,f.fecha,f.total,d.producto,d.cantidad,d.precio,d.subtotal FROM factura f,detalle d WHERE f.codigo=d.codigo;
END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Funciona hasta cierto punto,pues me trae los primeros datos, pero si yo selecciono uno de eso quiero que me traiga los otros datos

¿Como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

No me queda muy clara la necesidad. ¿Te refieres a que si selecciona el código 1, te traiga la factura y detalle de la misma? o ¿Te refieres a que pueda aplicar distintos filtros?

Quedamos atentos.

Comment: si, eso es ¿si se puede hacer ?

Comment: En otro foro ya habían hablado respecto al tema de devolver múltiples querys. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074281/postgresql-function-return-multiple-select-statements